# devide a JavaScript Object two separate variable

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I am trying to divide a JavaScript object into two separate arrays based in the fact if the value `contact` is null. I am having trouble storing the values into separate objects and I am not really sure how to store them in the respective object. I made a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uf9p01oa/17/) to help you play with this code.

```js
var data = [{
    address: "234 BLUE WAY",
    addressType: "Mailing",
    city: "DONKY KONG CITY",
    contact: null,
    country: "US",
    email: "JANEER@GMAIL.COM",
    zipCode: "44222"
  },
  {
    address: "123 GETYO WAY",
    addressType: "Mailing",
    city: "NARNIA",
    contact: "JAMES DO",
    country: "US",
    email: "JAMES@MYEMAIL.COM",
    zipCode: "13123"
  }

];

var empContactInfoAddress;
var emergencyContactInfoAddress;

for (let d in data) {
  if (data[d].contact == null) {

    Object.keys(data[d]).forEach((key) => {
      this.empContactInfoAddress[d][key] = data[d][key];
    });
  } else {
    Object.keys(data[d]).forEach((key) => {
      this.emergencyContactInfoAddress[d][key] = data[d][key];
    });

  }
}
console.log('empContactInfoAddress', this.empContactInfoAddress)
console.log('emergencyContactInfoAddress', this.emergencyContactInfoAddress)
```

Comment: FYI: Don't use `for ... in` for arrays, at some point you could accidentally iterate over a non-index property (ie a method name etc). Use `for ... of` for iterables like arrays

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can `filter()` based on the `contact` property.

If you have really large lists you can use something like `reduce` which  would let you do this with one one loop through the data. But `filter()` is  very easy to read, which for me balances the extra work unless there's a bottleneck.

```js
var data = [{address: "234 BLUE WAY",addressType: "Mailing",city: "DONKY KONG CITY",contact: null,country: "US",email: "JANEER@GMAIL.COM",zipCode: "44222"},{address: "123 GETYO WAY",addressType: "Mailing",city: "NARNIA",contact: "JAMES DO",country: "US",email: "JAMES@MYEMAIL.COM",zipCode: "13123"}];

let NoContact = data.filter(d =>  d.contact == undefined)
let Contact = data.filter(d => d.contact)

console.log("no contact: ", NoContact)
console.log("contact: ", Contact)
```

Comment: I just realize I was making this way more complicated and I never heard of filter. I am definitely going to use filter. Awesome! I have to wait a few minutes to accept this,

Comment: Yes @myhouse, `filter`, `reduce` and `map` are all wonderful tools to have.

Answer (score 2):

```js
var data = [{
    address: "234 BLUE WAY",
    addressType: "Mailing",
    city: "DONKY KONG CITY",
    contact: null,
    country: "US",
    email: "JANEER@GMAIL.COM",
    zipCode: "44222"
  },
  {
    address: "123 GETYO WAY",
    addressType: "Mailing",
    city: "NARNIA",
    contact: "JAMES DO",
    country: "US",
    email: "JAMES@MYEMAIL.COM",
    zipCode: "13123"
  }

];

data.forEach(function(arrayItem, i) {
  var x = arrayItem;
  console.log(x);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

To achieve expected result, use below option of using if condition and pushing to variables if contact is null

```js
var data = [
    {
        address: "234 BLUE WAY",
        addressType: "Mailing",
        city: "DONKY KONG CITY",
        contact: null,
        country: "US",
        email: "JANEER@GMAIL.COM",
        zipCode: "44222"
    },
    {
        address: "123 GETYO WAY",
        addressType: "Mailing",
        city: "NARNIA",
        contact: "JAMES DO",
        country: "US",
        email: "JAMES@MYEMAIL.COM",
        zipCode: "13123"
    }

];

var empContactInfoAddress =[];
var emergencyContactInfoAddress = [];

for (let d in data) {
   if(data[d].contact === null){
      empContactInfoAddress.push(data[d])
   }else{
     emergencyContactInfoAddress.push(data[d])
   }
}
console.log('empContactInfoAddress', empContactInfoAddress)
console.log('emergencyContactInfoAddress', emergencyContactInfoAddress)
```

Comment: Thanks. I actually realize my mistake shortly after I post this. It's been a long day. :)

Answer (score 1):

You could write a partition utility function

```
function partition(array, predicate) {
  const positives = array.filter(predicate);
  const negatives = array.filter(value => !predicate(value));
  return [positives, negatives];
}

const [
  empContactInfoAddress,
  emergencyContactInfoAddress
] = partition(data, d => !d.contact);
```